# Read and parse KML in java

Tags: java, parsing, kml

Is there any library available to parse KML ?

Comment: Here's my implementation with Jsoup
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140144/read-and-parse-kml-in-java/21283827#21283827

Answer (score 10):

You'll be making your own library, but you won't be writing any code.

I suggest looking at http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html. From there you can get the [XML Schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/). Once you've got the schema you can use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) to generate an object tree to easily parse and write KML.

[This may also be a good resource](http://acuriousanimal.blogspot.com/2008/08/using-jaxb-to-generate-kml-java-classes.html), looks like someone else has already done it!

Comment: I went down this road for a little practice, there's a little hiccup in that there are a couple of elements that collide when the schema is run through the compiler. Nothing major, but be prepared to write a few custom bindings.

Answer (score 7):

This library looks promising as well:

http://code.google.com/p/javaapiforkml/

The library provides support till now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my JSOUP implementation hope it helps

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> getCoordinateArrays() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> allTracks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>();

    try {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream json = MyApplication.getInstance().getAssets().open("track.kml");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(json));
        String str;
                      String buffer;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            buf.append(str);
        }

        in.close();
        String html = buf.toString();
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        ArrayList<String> tracksString = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element e : doc.select("coordinates")) {
            tracksString.add(e.toString().replace("<coordinates>", "").replace("</coordinates>", ""));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tracksString.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> oneTrack = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            ArrayList<String> oneTrackString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tracksString.get(i).split("\\s+")));
            for (int k = 1; k < oneTrackString.size(); k++) {
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(oneTrackString.get(k).split(",")[0]),
                        Double.parseDouble(oneTrackString.get(k).split(",")[1]));
                oneTrack.add(latLng);
            }
            allTracks.add(oneTrack);
        }}

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return allTracks;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is xml you can read the data with any parser but still there is an lib available at http://code.google.com/p/libkml/ it has bindings for java but the lib is in C++

Answer (score 1):

This is other options, the kml file is a normal file, who contain structure the xml file.
This is other example, for search one specific placemark in the file the multiple placemarks

```
private static void readKML(InputStream fileKML, String nameCoordinates) {
    String column = null;
    Boolean folder = Boolean.TRUE;
    Boolean placemark = Boolean.FALSE;
    Boolean placeCorrect = Boolean.FALSE;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileKML));
    try {
        while ((column = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (folder) {
                int ifolder = column.indexOf("<Folder>");
                if (ifolder != -1) {
                    folder = Boolean.FALSE;
                    placemark = Boolean.TRUE;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (placemark) {
                String tmpLine = nameCoordinates;
                tmpLine = tmpLine.replaceAll("\t", "");
                tmpLine = tmpLine.replaceAll(" ", "");
                String tmpColumn = column;
                tmpColumn = tmpColumn.replaceAll("\t", "");
                tmpColumn = tmpColumn.replaceAll(" ", "");
                int name = tmpColumn.indexOf(tmpLine);
                if (name != -1) {
                    placemark = Boolean.FALSE;
                    placeCorrect = Boolean.TRUE;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (placeCorrect) {
                int coordin = column.indexOf("<coordinates>");
                if (coordin != -1) {
                    String tmpCoordin = column;
                    tmpCoordin = tmpCoordin.replaceAll(" ", "");
                    tmpCoordin = tmpCoordin.replaceAll("\t", "");
                    tmpCoordin = tmpCoordin.replaceAll("<coordinates>", "");
                    tmpCoordin = tmpCoordin
                            .replaceAll("</coordinates>", "");
                    String[] coo = tmpCoordin.split(",");
                    System.out.println("LONG: "+coo[0]);
                    System.out.println("LATI: "+coo[1])
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cresp;
}
```

Comment: here is missing semicolon : System.out.println("LATI: "+coo[1])

Answer (score 0):

[osmbonuspack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/KML) works really well in case of handling kml data.

Answer (score 0):

if you use android studio :)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
}


      // find a way to read the file and store it in a string

       String inputFileContents = ""; 
        String xmlContent = inputFileContents;
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());

        for(Element e : doc.select("LineString").select("coordinates")) {
            // the contents
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
```

You can have multiple select() method calls.
I simplified the code to:

```
 Element e = doc.select("LineString").select("coordinates").first();
```

Comment: Error:(20, 29) java: no suitable method found for parse(org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings.Syntax,java.lang.String,org.jsoup.parser.Parser)
    method org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.jsoup.parser.Parser) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings.Syntax cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
    method

Comment: my imports:import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import static org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml;